# Appending not working on page retrieved from curl in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, curl

I am retrieving a page by using curl in php. So in the retrieved page, I want to add a new element using the append() method in jQuery. I can do it in my website which I have hosted. But it is not working in other well-known websites. Why it is not working?

php code

```
<?php 
// create curl resource 
$ch = curl_init(); 

// set url 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com"); 

//return the transfer as a string 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
// $output contains the output string 
$output = curl_exec($ch); 
echo $output;
if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
{
  echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
// close curl resource to free up system resources 
curl_close($ch);      
?>
```

Here is my jQuery and Ajax script

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/curlstart.php",
    success: function(data, textStatus ){
    alert(data);
    $("body").append(data);
    $(document.body).append("<p>Hello</p>");
   },
   error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
         alert("request failed in next year="+errorThrown);
      }
 });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your `url: "http://localhost:8080/curlstart.php",` -- it appears you're trying to reach localhost while on your hosted server. You could replace `http://localhost:8080/curlstart.php` with just `curlstart.php`.

Comment: Inhave written localhost because I am testing it on my PC from xampp.The above file curlstart is in my pc in htdocs folder